member scraper with pyrogram and asyncio
async def calistir():
                    app = Client(path + "\\users\\" + valmsj.get())
                    for uye in data:
                        try:
                            uye = uye["id"]
                            if run:
                                await app.add_chat_members(chat_id=kanal_id[k_id], user_ids=int(uye))
                                ekran.after(0, printt, f"{uye} - Eklendi")
                                await asyncio.sleep(int(yaz.get()))
                            else:
                                await app.stop()
                                break
                        except KeyboardInterrupt:pass
                        except PeerIdInvalid as e:
                            print(e)
                            ekran.after(0, printt, f"{uye} - Kullanıcı Yok")
                            await asyncio.sleep(int(yaz.get()))
                async with app:
                    await calistir()

I pull the id from the .json file and in the int value, so there is no problem with them, when I remove awaiti from the member pull function, it says that the member pull is successful, but it does not pull the member when I put awaiti.
Telegram says: [400 PEER_ID_INVALID] - The peer id being used is invalid or not known yet. Make sure you meet the peer before interacting with it
gives this peer id error
